# Form element values equal to another form values using a loop

Tags: javascript, forms, loops, text

I want to have text field values in one form equal to another form values when a radio button is checked. I can do it manually, but is there a way to do it using a loop? Thanks in advance!

```
<script type"text/javascript>

function setfields()
{

var radioSel = document.getElementById('radioChoice');

    if(radioSel.checked)
    {
    //loop to set fields
    }
}

</script>

<input name="radioChoice" type="radio" id="radioChoice" onChange="setFields">

<field set>
First Name:<input id="fname1" name="fname1" type="text"><br>
Last Name:<input id="lname1" name="lname1" type="text"><br>
</field set>

<!--make second field set values equal to first field set values-->

<field set>
First Name:<input id="fname2" name="fname2" type="text"><br>
Last Name:<input id="lname2" name="lname2" type="text"><br>
</field set>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the names (except the trailing `1` or `2`) in an array and iterate through that:

```
var names = ['fname', 'lname', ...];
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    var src = document.getElementById(names[i] + '1');
    var dst = document.getElementById(names[i] + '2');
    dst.value = src.value;
}
```

Or you could find the names yourself by iterating through children of the `<field>` block -- let's assume you've given the first one `id="fields1"`:

```
var fields = document.getElementById('fields1').childNodes;
for (var i = 0; i < fields1.length; i++) {
  if (fields[i].nodeType == 1 /*ELEMENT_NODE*/ && fields[i].tagName == 'input') {
    var baseId = fields[i].id.substr(0, fields[i].id.length - 1);
    document.getElementById(baseId + '2').value = fields[i].value;
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess I asked the wrong question. I want to copy the values from one form to the another using the count of elements in a field. Both forms contain identical info as shown above. I used your first answer and it workedfine, it's just not the approach I was looking for and that is not your fault. Thanks so much for your response!